# Does deleting variables before closing the tab/window help releasing memory?

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, memoization

I'm maintaining a JavaScript code where a function that does some heavy processing to generate arrays saves the results in a cache variable inside the function itself. It's implemented like this:

```
function heavyProcessingStuff(x) {
    if(heavyProcessingStuff.cache == undefined) 
       heavyProcessingStuff.cache = [];

    if(heavyProcessingStuff.cache[x] != undefined) {
       return heavyProcessingStuff.cache[x]
    } else {
      return heavyProcessingStuff.cache[x] = x + 1
    }
}
```

The weird thing is that there's a function executed when the page is unloaded that manually deletes every property of the cache variable, like this:

```
for (n in heavyProcessingStuff.cache) {
  delete heavyProcessingStuff.cache[n]
}
```

I'm confused about why this was implemented this way. 
Is this specific for some weird corner case? Is there any motivation to do so? Doesn't/shouldn't the browser garbage collect everything when the page closes?

Comment: I would guess your right. The browser handles it all. I can only assume its a throwback from C and old code that doesnt hurt to put in. Maybe some browsers back in the day were getting memory leaks, and this was a workaround.

Comment: Well, some browsers hold the page in memory when you navigate away, so they can return to it faster when you go back in history. Eventually, they will of course delete this cache.

Comment: The unload event is also called when the page is refreshed, perhaps they were having problems with the cache not clearing on refresh so they had to manually handle the clearing of the cache.

Comment: @PimpTrizkit I was *just* about to give you a vote until I read, "...that doesn't hurt to put in." It does in fact hurt, and could hurt substantially if there is a lot of `heavyProcessingStuff`, since it could hang the browser when they're trying to close the tab.

Comment: oh, duh, yes, your right! But other than that, i was supposing.

Comment: I've observed serious "carry-over" memory usage related to web applications that are intended to stay on the same page for long periods of time. When you navigate away, the browser seems to "hold on" to a lot of memory. This code would potentially reduce the reference count on those variables, but so (theoretically) would navigating away. Cleaning those references up doesn't dictate that the garbage collector will run, and until that happens there's no memory effect for the browser. The code is reasonable enough in theory, but I don't think it directly accomplishes anything in practice.

Comment: Did you, by any chance, do any benchmark testing with that code enabled & disabled? It seems the easiest way to decide if that is worth it is to gather enough data to prove it out either way. It is easy to dismiss this as an anachronism or pointless, but the fact is that there are enough variables in the mix with client operations that I really would have to prove this out with hard data before I would be comfortable removing it. I wouldn't go **add** something like this without evidence that it is useful, but since it is already there, I'd flip that around and prove it needs to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript uses garbage collection and it is best not to free memory explicitly. Good reading on this is in "De-referencing Misconceptions" in the article ["Writing Fast, Memory-Efficient JavaScript"](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/05/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/).

A quote from the article:

> It’s not possible to force garbage collection in JavaScript. You
>   wouldn’t want to do this, because the garbage collection process is
>   controlled by the runtime, and it generally knows best when things
>   should be cleaned up.

Comment: I believe your answer to be correct - and important. I suggest you give more specifics, perhaps quoting from the article you've given or you'll likely be overlooked.

Comment: Agreed Grinn, it would be nice to see this answer expanded to rely less on the link.

Comment: Added the quote from the article that applied best so that it endures if the link is removed.

Comment: There's a quote from this article that's intriguing to me, though. _"If you’re using a data cache locally, make sure to clean that cache or use an aging mechanism to avoid large chunks of data being stored that you’re unlikely to reuse"_. Isn't this exactly my case? Thanks for the answer anyway, great article.

Comment: @WilliamBarbosa: I guess this is specific for clientside storage technologies (Local/Session storage, Indexed DB, File System API etc) that the browser won't clean by itself.

Comment: When the page is unloaded, there will be no references to the data, so the garbage collector will collect it on its next pass. Garbage collectors are constantly optimized for best performance and, usually, when we try to collect things ourselves, at best code complexity is added, and at worst new bugs and reduced performance.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the full context, there is one other possibility:

Earlier versions of IE (I know IE6 was susceptible), used a simple reference counting system for garbage collection.  The trouble is that the DOM and JavaScript kept *separate* reference stacks.

This allowed for a situation to develop where the DOM (via an expando property) could hold onto a JavaScript reference -- and the JavaScript held onto a DOM reference.

This circular references would create a memory leak that lived on beyond the page, and the memory was only released when the <strike>page</strike> window was closed.

It was common to use the unload event to free memory and release any event handlers in an effort to avoid this.

Comment: "This circular references would create a memory leak that lived on beyond the page, and the memory was only released when the page was closed." Do you mean to say, "when the window was closed"?

Comment: You're welcome. I remember that bug, but I think this is just from some old-school programmer (or old code) that had the erroneous belief that deleting properties from an object would free up memory. Thanks for the trip down memory lane, though!

Comment: Nice guess. IE is, sadly enough, the main browser we develop for. I don't know if this piece of code was meant to support IE6, though. I'll comment here if I find out. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score -1):

In Chrome and Internet Explorer (or any browser that implements a process-per-tab model), you're right, there's absolutely no value. In fact, it's wasting CPU time to try and delete, since often when a tab is closed a process is killed, freeing up all non-shared resources.

For browsers that are a single process (Firefox still is, though progress is underway to change that), it's possible this could make the garbage collector do its work faster, if the reference counts get decremented to 0, but it's probably also pointless. Other than very old ([IE6 for example](http://foohack.com/2007/06/msie-memory-leaks/)) browsers, every modern garbage collector will probably sweep away everything on the next pass regardless of whether you explicitly remove references or not.

Comment: Just a note: As long as that objects stay in the same window this is true. If you have code that communicates between different windows (popups, iframes) and passes Objects between them, then this might be not true anymore. I know this is a special case, but a real one: ["A memory leak occurs in Internet Explorer 8 when you open and then close a new window or tab that contains circular references that involve the window object"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2711084/en-us). It is not a trivial task especially when the every window has it's own process.

Comment: Can you please substantiate, "For browsers that are a single process... this could make the garbage collector do its work faster"?